# difference between "日欧米で株上昇" and "日米欧で株上昇"?

Tags: words

"欧米{おうべい}" means "the Western countries (USA, Canada, Western Europe, Australia)". "欧米" is something that I've heard frequently in daily conversations.

So, the headline [日米欧で株上昇　日経平均は一時２００円超高](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASH1R369VH1RULFA007.html) caught my attention. Of course, newspapers are full of abbreviations. Here is my interpretation:

"日米欧で株上昇..."
*Stock prices increased in Japan, the USA, and Western Europe.*

"日欧米で株上昇..."
*Stock prices increased in Japan, the USA, Canada, Western Europe, and Australia.*

Is that what is going on in the title?

btw:
In a conversation, could I say "にちおうべい" to mean "Japan and the Western countries"? Could I say "にちおう" to exclusively mean "Japan and Western Europe"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I don't think Australia is included in 欧米 when it comes to the market, though)

欧米 is a word but either 日米欧 or 日欧米 are not a word but just three abbreviated words are put in a row and they both mean "Japan, the USA, and Europe. So, if you want to say "Japan and the Western countries", it should be 日本と欧米, not 日欧米. And, if you want to say exclusively "Japan and Western Europe" it's 日本と西欧 because 欧 includes eastern one too. Today, 日欧 often sands for "Japan and EU".